# Can we give instantaneous voltage higher than rated voltage of microcontroller?

Tags: power-supply, buck

Friend of mine has kit which has microcontroller controlling some sort of power circuit, the problem is it is some cheap Chinese kit and has no documentation whatsoever. However it's input voltage is rated at 24V and has current rating of 15A (yeah, 15 A). He has 28V source and I was about to suggest him buck converter to ensure input voltage is ~24V , but AFAIK, buck converter will have instantaneous voltage equal to supply voltage, so my question is, can we give instantaneous voltage more than the rated voltage of controller (actually its rated voltage of kit but we know nothing about how it's being stepped down and to what level it is being stepped down) if it's average value is within ratting?

Comment: If you have a "kit" with no documentation and you're not even sure what it does, why are you wasting time on it? More importantly, why do you want **us** to waste any time on it? This is an awfully broad reverse-engineering question that will be closed unless you can provide a lot more detail about what it is and what you hope to accomplish with it. See this meta post: [Explicit close reason: “OP bought undocumented stuff, asks us instead of seller for documentation”](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6469/11683)

Answer (score 2):

Read the number off of the voltage regulator and relevant related parts. Find the datasheet for the part(s). Understand the limitations described in the datasheet (make measurements if necessary). Decide if the part is capable of higher voltage input. You will learn a lot from this exercise. It is definitely going into a regulator since (almost) no microcontroller can accept a voltage like that directly. I say 'almost' because there are a few with shunt regulators on board, but you don't have one of those.

Usually the limitation on the high end is voltage rating (not minimum on time or anything else) since that results in less switch power dissipation.

For what it's worth I have seen items sold with specifications that exceed the datasheet maximum ratings (for example, meter modules that have maximum input voltage specified above the regulator maximum rating). The specifications are only as reliable as the entity composing them.

Comment: But if input voltage specified is 24V, is it instantaneous maximum or average maximum?

Comment: @Deep I have no idea. You need to worry about both. If it just says 24V (not 9-24VDC or something like that) it's "most likely" **nominal** input voltage and 28V is okay, but don't blame me if it fries.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the output rising to the input voltage, no.  The output of a properly designed buck regulator will hold the set voltage value, plus ripple voltage.